# Create RAID1 with luks without erase disks

Tags: ubuntu, raid, luks

I need to create a RAID1 arrange with an existing phisical disk. I buyed another hdd with same size and I want to create a RAID1 arrange without erasing the first one. My disk have luks encryption, I want to keep luks encryption in the Raid. I have any option?

- I mount manually the only encrypted disk that I have , for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the new disk the way you want it (with taid and one missing disk), then transfer everything to that new disk. Now add the original disk to the raid and let it mirror.